# Why the rush to get to the general in Blackadder?

Tags: plot-explanation, blackadder

In *Blackadder Goes Forth: General Hospital* Blackadder reveals that Nurse Mary is the spy.  She is lead away to be shot and then George reveals that he was really giving the information away by sending letters to his uncle.

Darling and Blackadder then race to the General to tell him.

Why?

Was she not a spy?  If not then why didn't she say so and why did she not spot that Hull was not one of the great universities?  Also, all of the evidence pointed towards her (speaking German, quizzing Blackadder over tank movements etc).

If she was a spy then why rush to tell the General, she would be shot anyway.

Answer (score 2):

Darling is typically Blackadder’s rival. In that scene Blackadder makes a big show of finding the spy for the General and makes a fool of Darling in the process(as usual).

Now they have both realised that the information was probably coming from George. Darling would want to tell the General of Blackadder’s mistake as soon as possible, while Blackadder would want to put his own spin on things or at the very least not allow Darling to turn the General against him.

Essentially it’s like two kids who hate each other and one just got a reason to tell on the other so they race to the closest authority figure.

Answer (score 1):

I would say that George's "confession" didn't *completely* exonerate Nurse Mary, but it *did* cast doubt. Capital punishment (such as the firing squad) requires no shadow of a doubt. After all, speaking good German isn't completely unheard of, and asking about military movements can be a simple act of (rash) curiosity. And I'm sure the fact that Edmund more than just fancied her a bit put a bit of fire in his step :)

Comment: Probably a little off topic, but (sadly) capital punishment during WW1 did not require "no shadow of doubt", simply the judgement of the officer presiding over the court-martial.